# What is the set FirstHalves B? You can simply write out the set explicitly, enumerating the first four values

Tags: complexity-theory, finite-automata

For any set of strings A, define the set FirstHalves A =  {x∣∃y such that len(y) = len(x) and xy in A }. For example, FirstHalves {01, 111, 1010, 001101, 1011} = {0, 10, 001}, ie the first halves of the even length strings.

Let B = {01, 011, 0111, 01111, 011111, ...}.
What is the set FirstHalves B? You can simply write out the set explicitly, enumerating the first four values.

- I tackled this question at first thinking that it is all even length strings and their first halves. So my first answer was {0, 01, 011, 0111, ....}

However, after having this checked the right answer is {0, 01, 0111, 01111}. Can someone help me understand why?

Comment: Where did you check the answer? Did you consider that there may be a mistake where you checked? Also the set $B$ is not clearly defined: what is the meaning of those …? Is $B$ the language $01^+$?

Answer (score 1):

Your first answer appears to be correct.   I think the other source is wrong.  In particular, 011 is in FirstHalves B because 011111 is in B.